# convert anchor tag to embed in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert an anchor that contains .pdf in the href with embed tag and href into src

```
<a href="www.google.com/pdf">Hello this is test</a>
```

This need to be changed in embed tag: as below output

```
<embed src="www.google.com/pdf">
```

Comment: I'm assuming `herf` is supposed to be `href`?

Comment: Dear @user9600582, I leave an upvote for you for more motivation.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this use `replaceWith()`. Provide a function to the method call which returns the new content, like this:

```js
$('a').replaceWith(function() {
  return `<embed src="${this.href}" />`;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.google.com/pdf">Hello this is test</a>
```

Note that you need to include the protocol in the absolute URL. Beginning it with `www` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure JavaScript solution for when you don't want jQuery:

```
const a = document.querySelector('a');
const e = document.createElement('embed');
e.setAttribute('src', a.href)
const aParent = a.parentElement;
const aNextSibling = a.nextElementSibling;

if (aNextSibling) {
  aParent.insertBefore(e, aNextSibling);
} else {
  aParent.appendChild(e);
}
a.remove();
```

Comment: I do believe your intentions are correct, neither was meant to be preachy (had plenty of these types of answers in [jquery] that say "stop using jquery") so may have gone a bit high-horse.  I've taken the liberty of rewording, hope that's acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the **outerHTML**.

```
$('a').each(function () {
    if (this.href.indexOf('pdf')) {  // checks whether href contains pdf
          this.outerHTML = "<embed src=" + this.href + ">";
    }
});
```